# Can I change the status(passed, failed, skipped) of a test from any JUnit 5 listener?

Tags: java, junit5

In TestNG I can set the final status of the tests using `ITestListener`.

Example:

```
public class TestListener implements ITestListener {
    
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
       result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);    
    }

}
```

Is this possible to be done in JUnit 5 and how?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do such a thing?

Comment: @DavidConrad I have soft verifications which I want to be automatically checked for failures when a test ends(I don't want to explicitly call `soft.assertAll()` at the end of each test). I don't see other option than to use listeners that run this check for soft failures after the test ends, and then set the test status accordingly.
But I am open for smarter suggestions :)

Comment: `org.assertj.core.api.junit.jupiter.SoftAssertionsExtension` already does what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SamBrannen not really, because you must call `assertAll()` explicitly at the end of the assertions :)

Comment: What are you talking about? Did you even look at `SoftAssertionsExtension`? As I said, it already does what you are trying to do. It invokes `assertAll()` for you. https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-junit5-soft-assertions

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TestWatcher interface from the `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api"`:

dependency:

`testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3")`

using:

```java
public class SomeTest implements TestWatcher, AfterAllCallback {
    public void testDisabled(ExtensionContext context, Optional<String> reason) {
        
    }
}
```

- All methods of the interface are "implemented" by default, so you don't have to override all of them.
- AfterAllCallback interface allow to you handle `afterAll()` method

I don't know which target you try to achieve, but you able to change the status of the result in following way:

```java
@Override
public void testFailed(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
    TestWatcher.super.testSuccessful(context);
}
```

Also you can implement `TestExecutionExceptionHandler` and handle `handleTestExecutionException`

Comment: I inspected the `TestWatcher`, but don't see any method of `context` that can set the test status. Do you spot such?

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev See update

Comment: I would also need to set the status to failed and attach throwable to it :) In TestNG, the `ITestResult` result has `result.setThrowable()`. In JUnit's `ExtensionContext ` all I see is getters, but no setters :(

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

I wasn't aware of this, but as pointed out by [Sam Brannen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77620334/3429133), there's already a [`SoftAssertionsExtension`](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-junit5-soft-assertions) that comes with AssertJ.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608468/can-i-change-the-statuspassed-failed-skipped-of-a-test-from-any-junit-5-list#comment136819569_77608468):

> I have soft verifications which I want to be automatically checked for failures when a test ends(I don't want to explicitly call `soft.assertAll()` at the end of each test). I don't see other option than to use listeners that run this check for soft failures after the test ends, and then set the test status accordingly. But I am open for smarter suggestions :)

You could write an [extension](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) that:

1. Creates a new `SoftAssertions` instance before each test
2. Provides the created `SoftAssertions` as a parameter
3. Calls `assertAll()` after each test

Extension:

```java
public class SoftAssertionsExtension
        extends TypeBasedParameterResolver<SoftAssertions>
        implements BeforeTestExecutionCallback, AfterTestExecutionCallback {

    private static final Namespace STORE_NAMESPACE = Namespace.create(SoftAssertionsExtension.class);
    private static final String STORE_KEY = SoftAssertions.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) {
        context.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE).put(STORE_KEY, new SoftAssertions());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) {
        context.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE).get(STORE_KEY, SoftAssertions.class).assertAll();
    }

    @Override
    public SoftAssertions resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext)
            throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return extensionContext.getStore(STORE_NAMESPACE).get(STORE_KEY, SoftAssertions.class);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```java
@ExtendWith(SoftAssertionsExtension.class)
class SoftAssertionsTest {

    @Test
    void passingTest(SoftAssertions softly) {
        softly.assertThat(true).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void failingTest(SoftAssertions softly) {
        softly.assertThat(true).isFalse();
    }

}
```

The test status is automatically set by the extension / `assertAll()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But seems that you just moved the `assertAll()` from the end of the method, to the beginning :)) You still have to write explicit code in each method(even though as method param)

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev I don't think I can follow you? `assertAll()` is _implicitly_ invoked _after_ each test. Would you mind adding an example to your question of how your test code (should) look(s) like?

Comment: I would prefer to not pass the soft asserts as parameter to all tests. But now as I am thinking - I can just not create the soft asserts in the `beforeTestExecution`. Of course I would need to have them use `ThreadLocal` for the failures caching.

So, your example could help me, but I need to experiment with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are seeking already exists and comes out of the box from AssertJ.

From the official [AssertJ documentation](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-junit5-soft-assertions):

> `SoftAssertionsExtension` is a JUnit 5 extension that:
>
> - takes care of calling `assertAll()` at the end of each tests
> - supports initializing `SoftAssertionsProvider` field annotated with `@InjectSoftAssertions`
> - supports injecting a `SoftAssertionsProvider` parameter in each test methods